# Proof about congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $$f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$$

where $a_0,...,a_n$ are integers.Show that if d consecutive values of (i.e, values for consecutive integers) are all divisible by the integer d, then $d|f(x)$ for all integral x. Show by an example that this sometimes happens with $d>1$ even when $(a_0,....,a_n)=1$

I am still trying to understand the problem. so if we show that $d|f(x)$ for $x=t,x=t+1,....,x=t+d-1$ where t is some integer then $d|f(x)$ for all integral x. What does all integral x mean?

Comment: "all integral x" means "all x where x is an integer".

Comment: so we have to show that it works for $x=t-r$ and $x=t+d-1+r$ where r is an integer

Comment: Yes, that is correct. where r is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d$ be the $d$ consecutive integers such that $f(x_i)$ is a multiple of $d$. Then every integer $y$ can be written $y=dq+x_i$, for some $i$ (*). Now compute $f(y) = f(dq+x_i) \bmod d$.

(*) Because the $x_i$ form a complete set of residues mod $d$. This is the crucial point. They being consecutive guarantees this but is not necessary.

Comment: the chapter I am reading doesn't cover anything about complete set of residues."Then every integer yy can be written y=dq+xi" Where did u get this?

Comment: I think I got it. Every integer is either congruent to  $0mod(d),1mod(d),....,d-1mod (d)$. Hence d consecutive integers forms a complete residue system in mod d then we just pick the one which corresponds to the same $ymod(d)$. Subtracting two things congruent to the same $ymod(d)$ leads to something that is congruent to $0 (mod) d$ and then the proof is completed by mathguy's criteria.

Comment: Thanks for showing the stuff of complete set of residues. Very useful tool for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the example: $2 \mid (x^2 + x)$ for all integers $x$.

For the proof part: show that if $d \mid (x_1 - x_2)$ then also $d \mid (f(x_1) - f(x_2))$. Then, for any integer $x,\,$ there is a number $y$ between $t$ and $t+d-1$ (using your notation) so that $d \mid (x-y)$. Since $d \mid (f(x) - f(y))$ by what you already proved, and $d \mid f(y)$ by assumption, you get $d \mid f(x).$

Comment: what about if $x<d$?

Comment: What about it?  What is your question?

Comment: so I have to find a y between t and $t+d-1$  such that   $ t \leq x+py \leq t+d-1$ where p is an integer

Comment: I don't know....

Comment: I don't know..... "then, for any integer x,x, there is a number y between t and t+d−1 (using your notation) so that d∣(x−y)d∣(x−y)". How do you show this?

Comment: I think I got it. Every integer is either congruent to  $0mod(d),1mod(d),....,d-1mod (d)$. Hence d consecutive integers forms a complete residue system in mod d then we just pick the one which corresponds to the same $ymod(d)$. Subtracting two things congruent to the same $ymod(d)$ leads to something that is congruent to $0 (mod) d$.